# Does this table/view that I created on AWS Athena, gets refreshed as the data in s3 gets updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am preparing data from on AWS Athena using s3 bucket.  .My data on S3 keeps on updating everyday , so I would need the AWS Athena to get updated.so that my visuals also get updated.

Answer (score 1):

Athena does not store any data. Its a adhoc query engine. So athena query will return latest data from S3 as data gets updated. Just make sure, if there are multiple files coming in S3 for same table, your Athena table points to the whole folder.